# Find a key in Dictionary and access its value containing a KeyValue pair of Strings

Tags: javascript, c#

I've got a dictionary of `<long, List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` which I'm trying to access in JavaScript.

```
var data = new Dictionary<long, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>();
```

e.g: `data` would have `Key:100`, `Value: Name, John`

In Javascript,
I need to get all `KeyValuePair<string,string>`in `data` and add it into `mu.Mappings` using the `long` key.

```
ViewModel.Degrees.forEach(function(mu) {
     mu.Mappings = ViewModel.MappingListResults.Keys(mu.ID)
    .find((value => ViewModel.MappingListResults[key] === mu.ID)); //doesn't work  
});
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Could do with a bit more detail here; you've given the C# type you have, but no names, then a block of js code that has names but "doesn't work". For example, telling us what JSON the C# data structure serializes to would probably make things a lot easier

Comment: @CaiusJard I've edited the post. Hope this is better.